# Confusion regarding fermi-dirac distribution function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

The fermi dirac distribution function given in http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/disfd.html is different from what I learnt. What I learnt had the chemical potential $\mu$ in place of $E_F$ . Isn't $\mu$ only equal to $E_F$ when $T = 0$ ? Or am I mixing stuff up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solid state physics, especially in the subfield of electronic devices, it is not uncommon to use Fermi energy as a *synonym* of chemical potential. Some texts explicitly disclose this possible source of confusion and misusage  of the term Fermi energy, others do not.